# How to control what can and what cannot be derived outside the assembly?

Tags: c#, inheritance, derived-types

Let's say I have a base class `B`, which has to be exported from the assembly. There are two classes, `D1` and `D2` deriving from `B` and I want them to be the only ones deriving from it. My goals are:

- Make `B` visible outside the assembly;
- Disallow deriving or instantiating `B`;
- Export `D1` and `D2` and disallow deriving from them as well.

What for? Let's say, I require external class to provide a list of `B`s, which can consist only of `D1`s or `D2`s.

How can I do it?

Comment: why post the question, when you know the answer?

Comment: @Ehsan That is actually an allowed action on StackOverflow as it creates a point of reference for future search. Assuming, of course, that this isn't actually creating a duplicate. In this case I think the question title could be better, but I cannot initially think of how to re-word it.

Comment: @Ehsan Click "Ask Question" and look below the input field, you'll find a checkbox `Answer your own question – share your knowledge, Q&A-style`

Answer (score 3):

The solution is:

- Make `B` public and abstract;
- Make all `B`'s constructors `internal`;
- Make `D1` and `D2` sealed.

Noone will be able to derive from `B`, because he won't be able to call `B`'s constructor. Deriving from `D1` and `D2` won't be available, because they are sealed. But all classes will be available outside the assembly, since they are public.

```
public abstract class B
{
    internal B()
    {
    }
}

public sealed class D1 : B
{

}

public sealed class D2 : B
{

}
```